# VBScript - "Type Mismatch" Error with InStr Function

Tags: string, vbscript, type-mismatch

I have a String like this:

```
"5/1/2017 7:11:15 PM | String is very long - part 1 - part 999 - 2017-04-28.dots, Replace Existing"
```

This is the sub string I want to find the position in main string:

```
"String is very long - part 1 - part 999 - 2017-04-28.dots"
```

I tried to find it using `InStr` Function like this:

```
MsgBox CStr(InStr("5/1/2017 7:11:15 PM | String is very long - part 1 - part 999 - 2017-04-28.dots, Replace Existing", "String is very long - part 1 - part 999 - 2017-04-28.dots", 1, 1))
```

The result I expected is `23`.

Instead of the result, it throws the following Error:

> Type mismatch: '[string: "5/1/2017 7:11:15 PM"]' (Code: 800A000D)

As this error depicts, can't I use `InStr` Function to deal with Strings those have spaces?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_instr.asp

You are giving InStr 4 parameters, which means it is expecting the first to be an integer indicating where in the string to start the search. So, since it is expecting an integer, and you're giving it a string, it throws the Type Mismatch.

Just move one of the `1`s to be the first argument.

Comment: Thanks, I am sad to misplace parameters, but will it work with such long strings with spaces?

Comment: It should; there's nothing special about spaces in this case.